# Prevent XSLT replacing &#160; with &#nbsp;

Tags: xslt

How to prevent XSLT from replacing `&#160;` with `&#nbsp;`

*input.xml*

```
<span style='font:7.0pt "Times New Roman"'>&#160;&#160;&#160;&#160;&#160;
```

*output.xml*

```
<span style="font: 7.0pt&amp;#34;Times New Roman&amp;#34;">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nb
```

If I use `<xsl:output method="xml"/>` then `&#160;` is replaced with Â which I would also like to avoid.

*output.xml with method="xml"*

```
<span style="font: 7.0pt&amp;#34;Times New Roman&amp;#34;">Â Â Â Â Â Â Â Â Â
```

Also how to prevent it from replacing double quote with `&amp;#34;`

I am trying to use multiple XSLT files in a chain but first XSLT competely messes up the code as shown above.

I was also using following code to allow me to work with `&#nbsp;` in the original HTML but I don't know how to put that into resulting XML file in which case I wouldn't mide having `&#nbsp;` in output.xml

```
<!DOCTYPE doctypeName [
   <!ENTITY nbsp "&#160;">
]>
```

I have been trying to fix this for hours.

Comment: what is your context (what programming language), AND what XSLT processor and version are you using. Good luck.

Comment: Your "problem" output is due to viewing it with the wrong character encoding settings.

Comment: Eclipse XSLT 2,0 Saxon. These A characters show up in Web Browser so I can't have them. Then how do I tell XSLT to insert that DOCTYPE snippet into resulting XML so that &nbsp; isnt' making problems for the next XSLT in the chain?

Comment: And you seem to have a "double escape".  There should not be anything like `&amp;#34;`.

Comment: It seems that the biggere problem are these nbsp. It seems that I can

Comment: It seems that I can't use method="html" because then the formating is all wrong like <br>. So i guess I have to use method="xml" which creates that A characters that show up in the output.

Answer (score 2):

Saxon will only inject `&nbsp;` into the output if the output method is HTML. If the subsequent steps in the pipeline are expecting XML then you obviously shouldn't be doing that. But if the subsequent steps expect XML then they should have no difficulty with the NBSP character appearing as itself (unescaped).

Saxon will of course not output NBSP as "Â", but it will output a UTF-8 character that might look like "Â" if you view it using software that doesn't understand UTF-8.

If you want more control over the representation of non-ascii characters (which you shouldn't actually need), then you could try setting encoding="us-ascii", or you could try the saxon:character-representation attribute in xsl:output.

Answer (score 1):

> If I use `<xsl:output method="xml"/>` then   is replaced with Â
>   which I would also like to avoid.

Try:

```
<xsl:output method="xml" encoding="ascii"/>
```

http://xsltransform.net/bdxtqJ